# PHP - PDO: Syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, I got this syntax error but I can't figure it out

```
$pageid = $_GET['pageid'];
$sql = "SELECT article_id FROM page_content WHERE id='" .$pageid ."'";
$row = $conn->query($sql);
if ($row != false){
    $result = $row->fetch();
    $sql = "SELECT html_code from article WHERE id=" .$result['article_id'];
    $row = $conn->query(&sql);
    if ($row != false){
        $result = $row->fetch();
        echo $result['html_code'];
    }
}
```

Result: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in the line 7.
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `&` not a `$` for the variable so change this:

```
$row = $conn->query(&sql);
```

to this:

```
$row = $conn->query($sql);
```